# Changes not saved to database in release configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject

I have an issue where my changes are not saved to the database. No error is thrown either.
Here's the strange part. It only occurs when the solution is in Release configuration.

I have no idea why this happens. My first thought was that `UnitOfWork` wasn't injected with the same `DbContext` as the repository. But I do bind my `DbContext` with `InRequestScope` so that shouldn't be the case.

I have abstracted Entity Frameworks DbContext the following way:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public int Save()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    // omitted...
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public GenericRepository(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    // omitted...
}
```

My binding is setup this way:

```
kernel.Bind<MyContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
kernel.Bind(typeof(IGenericRepository<>)).To(typeof(GenericRepository<>));
```

Note the DbContext is bound with `.InRequestScope()`.

My controllers look like this:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IGenericRepository<foo> _fooRepository;

    public FooController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IGenericRepository<foo> fooRepository)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _fooRepository = fooRepository;
    }

    public ActionResult Update(Foo foo)
    {
        _fooRepository.Update(foo);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }

    // omitted...
}
```

Can you spot the error?

Comment: I am not sure whether the problem is located in the source code. Have you checked the project settings in configuration manager (menu Build / Configuration Manager) for any differences between Debug and Release build?

Comment: They're all set as Release and Any CPU when in Release config. However I tried setting all my bindings to InRequestScope and that works, at least in my initial test.

Comment: Did you set your connection string into the webconfig file? As you can have a different webconfig file in debug and release

Comment: In the effort to solve this issue I used the exact same connection string in both debug and release. The error existed both on my local machine and when published

Answer (score 0):

Setting all binds to `InRequestScope` appears to have fixed it.
I was under the assumption that Ninject was aware that an injected dependency was bound to `InRequestScope` and therefore recreated the dependent as needed.

That doesn't appear to be the case.

```
kernel.Bind<MyContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(IGenericRepository<>)).To(typeof(GenericRepository<>)).InRequestScope();
```